# waiting for my code to finish getting all info from API call using Kotlin

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, foreach, async-await

Hi I am new to Kotlin

I am trying to write the following code -

```
private fun syncLocalCartItemsToNetwork(tokenObject: MyVerteUserAuthTokenObject) {
        val failedSyncedProducts: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()


        locallySavedCartModels.forEach { //I need to make the code wait until all callbacks from this loop finishes
            ShoppingCartUtils.addItemToCart(tokenObject.token, it, this@ShoppingCartActivity, object : ShoppingCartUtils.OnMyVerteCartProductsSyncListener {
                override fun onProductSyncFailed(productID: String) {
                    failedSyncedProducts.add(productID)
                }
            })
        }

        if (failedSyncedProducts.isNotEmpty()) {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setTitle("Shopping Cart was not fully synced")
            builder.setMessage("The following items were not synced well due to stock availability, please re add them - \n\n" +
                    "${failedSyncedProducts.forEach { it + "\n\n" }}")
            builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()
        }
        Toast.makeText(this@ShoppingCartActivity, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


    }
```

As you can see, I am iterating through all the `locallySavedCartModels` and possibly get a result from it.

What I need is the option to make the fuction wait until all callbacks finish from the forEach loop, only then continue with my code to checking if my String list is empty or not.

How can I do that using Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would likely be cleanest to use coroutines, but that would mean rewriting your ShoppingCartUtils to use suspend functions instead of callbacks.

To work with what you have, one way might be to create a class that executes your remaining code when it has been called enough times, like this:

```
class CallbackAggregator(val count: Int) {
    var finalCallback: (() -> Unit)? = null
    private var calls = 0

    fun increment() {
        if (++calls == count)
            finalCallback?.invoke()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private fun syncLocalCartItemsToNetwork(tokenObject: MyVerteUserAuthTokenObject) {
    val failedSyncedProducts: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    val aggregator = CallbackAggregator(locallySavedCartModels.size)

    locallySavedCartModels.forEach { 
        ShoppingCartUtils.addItemToCart(tokenObject.token, it, this@ShoppingCartActivity, object : ShoppingCartUtils.OnMyVerteCartProductsSyncListener {
                override fun onProductSyncFailed(productID: String) {
                    failedSyncedProducts.add(productID)
                    aggregator.increment()
                }
            })
        }

    aggregator.finalCallback = {
        if (failedSyncedProducts.isNotEmpty()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(this@ShoppingCartActivity).apply {
                title = "Shopping Cart was not fully synced"
                message = "The following items were not synced well due to stock availability, please re add them - \n\n" +
                    "${failedSyncedProducts.joinToString("\n\n")}")
                setPositiveButton("Confirm") { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                create().show()
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this@ShoppingCartActivity, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if your asynchronous function `addItemToCart` is doing network actions, you likely need to implement some way to cancel its calls if the Activity is destroyed so you don't leak the Activity (because the callback objects capture a reference to it). But this would always be the case when doing network actions with a callback. You can find other questions on this site that address that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 

How would you recommend dealing with activity leaking? If needed I can provide my activity

Comment: I don't know what `addItemToCart` is doing behind the scenes, but you should add a function that can cancel the requests you have sent to it, also dropping any references to the callbacks. Call this cancel function from your `activity.onDestroy()`. This will remove all the objects that are holding a reference to the Activity, so the garbage collector can free its memory.

Comment: Just checked your solution and it seems like the aggregator function is being called before the callbacks finish so it does not work...

Comment: I double-checked it and don't see any errors. I of course can't test it myself because it's dependent on your project. It would fail if for some reason `addItemToCart` can possibly call a submitted callback more than once. You could log the `productID` before the `aggregator.increment()` line to check if that's happening.

Comment: Here I tested it by simulating some asynchronous actions with callbacks: https://pl.kotl.in/ZPDGITDV4